# Unable to UPDATE a table based on another table's information

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-error-1064

I have two tables. They both share the same member_id. I'm trying to update one of them based on the other table's information.

I am trying the following command:

```
UPDATE pfields_cont p, members m
   SET m.member_group_id = 6
 WHERE p.member_id = m.member_id
   AND p.field_2 = 'Teacher';
```

But I am getting:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=296263370) You have an error in your
> SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
> version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE pfields_cont p,
> members m

Comment: The error indicates that the query didn't start with `UPDATE`. The query [is valid](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0dc2039e272b6379d0ee05d5efb7e487)

Comment: @FaNo_FN what do you think is causing the issue then?

Comment: a previous query in your script with a missing semicolon at the end or some other error

Comment: while this query is valid, you should never use the old comma-join syntax anymore; always use explicit joins:  `UPDATE pfields_cont p INNER JOIN members m ON p.member_id=m.member_id WHERE p.field_2 = 'Teacher';`

Comment: @ysth thanks! Would you tell me why though, in simple words?

Comment: You can find [questions about the comma-join and JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+difference+between+comma-join+and+join) differences on this site but basically comma-join is deprecated and can generally emulates `JOIN/INNER JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN` only. Whereas `JOIN` can do [more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE members m
SET member_group_id = 6
from pfields_cont p
WHERE p.member_id = m.member_id
AND p.field_2 = Teacher';

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).